# How to fix : Error: Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to connect remotely on a mongodb server throw my local machine, but i'm having some issues.

On the remote server i modified the 'mongod.cfg' file and i changed the bindIp from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 to allow access. In the same file i changed the security by adding Authentication: 'enabled'.

I created an admin user:

```
> use admin
> db.createUser({user: "root", pwd: "root", roles:["root"]})
```

I started mongodb with --auth flag

```
> mongod --auth --port 27017
```

Once the server was up, i connect to it as administrator

```
mongo 127.0.0.1:27017 -u "root" -p "root" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

Once i was connected, i created a normal user

```
> use base
> db.createUser({user: "base", pwd: "base", roles:["dbOwner"]})
```

Then i disconnected from mongo shell and reconnected with new user credentials

```
> mongo <127.0.0.1:27017>/base -u "base" -p "base"
```

It worked properly on the remote server.

On the local machine i tried the same command on my local machine and it failed

```
> mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/base -u "base" -p "base"
[js] Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: If I understood it correctly you have 2 machines. From one machine you want to connect to mongod on other machine. If that is the case then from client machine you cannot use 127.0.0.1 ip for connecting mongod on other machine. You need to check other public/private ips available on server machine then use the ip from correct subnet.

Comment: @vk-code how can i check that and choose the right one?

Comment: assuming it's all linux, 'netstat -nap | grep mongod' will give you the IPs mongod is using. then use one of the IPs.

Comment: @vk-code the server machine is under windows10

Comment: for windows 10 what you can do is following `tasklist | findstr mongod` to get the pid of the mongod then `netstat -ano | findstr PID` to get the ip on which mongod is running. Then use this IP as suggested earlier.

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 is making reference to the localhost of the host machine, you need to set the user in both machines if you are going to use one, if you want to use a db that share the data in the cloud you can use [Mlab](https://mlab.com/) or if both ip are in the same network you can make reference from one to another by the ip address

```
mongo <ip_address>:27017/base -u "base" -p "base"
```